# How do I convert this HTML-table layout solution to floating-div solution?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-float

I often need to list items with various-sized **images** on the left and **text** on the right, like this:

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/7s01l5.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/7s01l5.png)

For 17 years, I have solved this with **HTML tables**, like this:

```
<html>

  <style>

    * { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

    body {
      padding: 20px;
    } 

    #content {
      width: 600px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      background: green;  
    }

    .item {
      margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    }

    .itemIcon {
      float:left;
    }

    .itemBody {
      float:right;
    }

    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }

  </style>

<body>

<div id="content">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="itemIcon">
      <img src="icon.png" alt=""/>  
    </div>
    <div class="itemBody">
      <h1>This is the first item</h1>
      <p>Aliquid aliquam fabulas duo an, eu delenit intellegebat has, in sit commodo aliquip. Inermis neglegentur vis an, ea mei habeo animal verterem. Cum vivendo intellegam disputando id, usu id dicta harum convenire. Cibo corpora ut pri, sed legere probatus aliquyam no, vidisse suscipiantur eu mea. Modus etiam concludaturque pro an, ut latine quaeque per. Harum ignota mnesarchum pri ad, duo et diam oblique epicurei, pri ne vivendo omnesque epicurei.</p> 
    </div> 
    <br class="clear"/>
  </div>

  <div class="item">  
    <div class="itemIcon">
      <img src="bigIcon.png" alt=""/>  
    </div>
    <div class="itemBody">
      <h1>This is the second item</h1>
      <p>Aliquid aliquam fabulas duo an, eu delenit intellegebat has, in sit commodo aliquip. Inermis neglegentur vis an, ea mei habeo animal verterem. Cum vivendo intellegam disputando id, usu id dicta harum convenire. Cibo corpora ut pri, sed legere probatus aliquyam no, vidisse suscipiantur eu mea. Modus etiam concludaturque pro an, ut latine quaeque per. Harum ignota mnesarchum pri ad, duo et diam oblique epicurei, pri ne vivendo omnesque epicurei.</p> 
    </div>    
    <br class="clear"/>
  </div> 

  <div class="item">
    <div class="itemIcon">
      <img src="icon.png" alt=""/>  
    </div>
    <div class="itemBody">
      <h1>This is the first item</h1>
      <p>Aliquid aliquam fabulas duo an, eu delenit intellegebat has, in sit commodo aliquip. Inermis neglegentur vis an, ea mei habeo animal verterem. Cum vivendo intellegam disputando id, usu id dicta harum convenire. Cibo corpora ut pri, sed legere probatus aliquyam no, vidisse suscipiantur eu mea. Modus etiam concludaturque pro an, ut latine quaeque per. Harum ignota mnesarchum pri ad, duo et diam oblique epicurei, pri ne vivendo omnesque epicurei.</p> 
    </div> 
    <br class="clear"/>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Everytime I have tried to switch to **floating divs**, it has **failed** for one reason or another, here is my **current attempt**:

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/tuvquv.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/tuvquv.png)

What do I have to **change** to this code so that this **div** solution looks like the **table** solution?

```
<html>

  <style>

    * { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

    body {
      padding: 20px;
    } 

    #content {
      width: 600px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      background: green;  
    }

    .item {
      margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    }

    .itemIcon {
      float:left;
    }

    .itemBody {
      float:right;
    }

    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }

  </style>

<body>

<div id="content">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="itemIcon">
      <img src="icon.png" alt=""/>  
    </div>
    <div class="itemBody">
      <h1>This is the first item</h1>
      <p>Aliquid aliquam fabulas duo an, eu delenit intellegebat has, in sit commodo aliquip. Inermis neglegentur vis an, ea mei habeo animal verterem. Cum vivendo intellegam disputando id, usu id dicta harum convenire. Cibo corpora ut pri, sed legere probatus aliquyam no, vidisse suscipiantur eu mea. Modus etiam concludaturque pro an, ut latine quaeque per. Harum ignota mnesarchum pri ad, duo et diam oblique epicurei, pri ne vivendo omnesque epicurei.</p> 
    </div> 
    <br class="clear"/>
  </div>

  <div class="item">  
    <div class="itemIcon">
      <img src="bigIcon.png" alt=""/>  
    </div>
    <div class="itemBody">
      <h1>This is the second item</h1>
      <p>Aliquid aliquam fabulas duo an, eu delenit intellegebat has, in sit commodo aliquip. Inermis neglegentur vis an, ea mei habeo animal verterem. Cum vivendo intellegam disputando id, usu id dicta harum convenire. Cibo corpora ut pri, sed legere probatus aliquyam no, vidisse suscipiantur eu mea. Modus etiam concludaturque pro an, ut latine quaeque per. Harum ignota mnesarchum pri ad, duo et diam oblique epicurei, pri ne vivendo omnesque epicurei.</p> 
    </div>    
    <br class="clear"/>
  </div> 

  <div class="item">
    <div class="itemIcon">
      <img src="icon.png" alt=""/>  
    </div>
    <div class="itemBody">
      <h1>This is the first item</h1>
      <p>Aliquid aliquam fabulas duo an, eu delenit intellegebat has, in sit commodo aliquip. Inermis neglegentur vis an, ea mei habeo animal verterem. Cum vivendo intellegam disputando id, usu id dicta harum convenire. Cibo corpora ut pri, sed legere probatus aliquyam no, vidisse suscipiantur eu mea. Modus etiam concludaturque pro an, ut latine quaeque per. Harum ignota mnesarchum pri ad, duo et diam oblique epicurei, pri ne vivendo omnesque epicurei.</p> 
    </div> 
    <br class="clear"/>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looking back to see that you want the height of the image container to push down (ala 100% height with overflow: hidden on it's parent)... there's not a pure CSS way to do this (without hacking). Since I dislike hacks probably more than un-semantic markup, I remove my answer :P

Comment: I dunno Timothy, my example seems to work, although admittedly I've only looked @ it in IE7 & Firefox. The only drawback to my solution is having to set the padding/margin depending on each image.

Comment: So why switch to divs if it's worked with tables for 17 years? Just because everyone scoffs at using tables for layout doesn't mean it's wrong, I think using divs is just the "in thing" to do, but it doesn't mean it's always the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't terribly flexible - you have to set the padding for each DIV depending on the image, but its very clean markup wise:

```
<style>
div.one {
   padding-left: 210px;
   overflow: auto;
}
div.one img {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -210px;
}
</style>


<div class="one">
<img src="http://www.pixeloution.com/breakdown.png" width="200" />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum blandit orci sed turpis aliquet ac mattis sem t...
</div>
```

See it in action at: http://jsbin.com/iniqu3/2

Notice if you make your screen very narrow, the text does not wrap around the image, as per your example.

Comment: And you can overwrite the div.one and div.one img styles by giving the div different classes and using the cascade, if the possible sizes are known. div.one.big { padding-left:300px; } div.one.big img { margin-left:-300px } and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it sort-of work by adding a width to the `<p>` within itemBody (and some padding to make it nice):

```
.itemBody p { 
  width:400px;
  padding-left:20px;
}

.itemBody h1 { 
  padding-left:20px;
}
```

The problem with this solution is that the right edges of the paragraphs will be aligned differently depending on the image size, and the text could still fall to the next line if the image is pretty wide. If you can dynamically size things with server-side code based on the image size, then this would be ok. (Or I suppose you could do the resizing in javascript.)

I really think this is a problem still best solved with tables. You get the dynamic width adjustment and everything stays on the same line, no matter what size your images and text are. No hacks, no fuss, works in all browsers.