# Is there a way for CSS to determine and adjust for image widths?

Tags: css, html

Thanks to [Erik's help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351125/how-do-i-convert-this-html-table-layout-solution-to-floating-div-solution/2351178#2351178) on my last question, I was able to get my icon-left, text-right floating div example working:

http://tanguay.info/web/examples/tablelessItemLayout

[image]
<sub>(source: [tanguay.info](http://tanguay.info/web/customImages/itemTypes/codeExamples/tablelessItemLayout.png))</sub>

However, because the images are various width's, I had to cheat a bit by putting in-line styles in some of the tags.

**How can I change this code so that:**

- **there are no in-line styles**
- **it supports various sized image widths**

Code:

```
<html>

  <style>

    * { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

    body {
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #333;
    } 

    p {
      margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }

    #content {
      width: 600px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      background: brown;
      border: 1px solid #555;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .item {
      margin: 20px;
      background-image:url('paperBackground.jpg');
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .itemIcon {
      float:left;         
    }

    .itemIcon p {
      font-size: 8pt;
      margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    }

    .itemBody h1 {
      font-size: 18pt;
      color: brown;
      margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }

    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }

  </style>

<body>

<div id="content">

  <div class="item">   
    <div class="itemIcon" style="width: 70px; padding-left: -80px">
      <img src="icon.png" alt=""/> 
      <p>This is the caption that is under the image.</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="itemBody" style="margin-left: 80px">    
      <h1>This is the first item</h1>
      <p>Aliquid aliquam fabulas duo an, eu delenit intellegebat has, in sit commodo aliquip. Inermis neglegentur vis an, ea mei habeo animal verterem. Cum vivendo intellegam disputando id, usu id dicta harum convenire. Cibo corpora ut pri, sed legere probatus aliquyam no, vidisse suscipiantur eu mea. Modus etiam concludaturque pro an, ut latine quaeque per. Harum ignota mnesarchum pri ad, duo et diam oblique epicurei, pri ne vivendo omnesque epicurei.</p> 
      <p>Aliquid aliquam fabulas duo an, eu delenit intellegebat has, in sit commodo aliquip. Inermis neglegentur vis an, ea mei habeo animal verterem. Cum vivendo intellegam disputando id, usu id dicta harum convenire. Cibo corpora ut pri, sed legere probatus aliquyam no, vidisse suscipiantur eu mea. Modus etiam concludaturque pro an, ut latine quaeque per. Harum ignota mnesarchum pri ad, duo et diam oblique epicurei, pri ne vivendo omnesque epicurei.</p> 
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="item">  
    <div class="itemIcon" style="width: 160px; padding-left: -170px">
      <img src="bigIcon.png" alt=""/> 
      <p>This is the caption that is under the image and it is a very long text so it is going to wrap a couple times here in the left column under the image.</p>  
    </div>
    <div class="itemBody" style="margin-left: 170px">  
      <h1>This is the second item</h1>
      <p>Aliquid aliquam fabulas duo an, eu delenit intellegebat has, in sit commodo aliquip. Inermis neglegentur vis an, ea mei habeo animal verterem. Cum vivendo intellegam disputando id, usu id dicta harum convenire. Cibo corpora ut pri, sed legere probatus aliquyam no, vidisse suscipiantur eu mea. Modus etiam concludaturque pro an, ut latine quaeque per. Harum ignota mnesarchum pri ad, duo et diam oblique epicurei, pri ne vivendo omnesque epicurei.</p> 
      <p>Aliquid aliquam fabulas duo an, eu delenit intellegebat has, in sit commodo aliquip. Inermis neglegentur vis an, ea mei habeo animal verterem. Cum vivendo intellegam disputando id, usu id dicta harum convenire. Cibo corpora ut pri, sed legere probatus aliquyam no, vidisse suscipiantur eu mea. Modus etiam concludaturque pro an, ut latine quaeque per. Harum ignota mnesarchum pri ad, duo et diam oblique epicurei, pri ne vivendo omnesque epicurei.</p> 
    </div>    
  </div> 

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you just force the image size on the CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove those custom inline margins and paddings if you add `overflow: auto` to the `.itemBody` instead:

```
.itemIcon {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.itemBody {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

You will not, however, be able to get rid of that inline width on the `.itemIcon` like this, because there's no way in CSS to limit the width of the `<p>` to the width of the image that precedes it. If you only have an image, though and no text to go along with it, you don't need the width.

You *can* get rid of the inline styles altogether, though, if you use CSS tables:

```
.itemIcon {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.itemBody {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The `width: 100%` on the `itemBody` forces the width of the `itemIcon` down to its minimum width, which is determined by the width of the image. The `vertical-align: top` will stop the first line of the `itemBody` from lining up with the image/text in the `itemIcon` "table column".

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to your problem is probably to modify the CSS dynamically with JavaScript.  [JQuery's .width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) allows you to do things like get the width of an image, and [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/CSS/) can be used to modify the CSS of an element (including width, margin, and padding). My suggestion would be to add an ID to each `itemIcon` and `itemBody`, then use the [onload() event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) to style the divs appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone can give you a div/css based solution. But in order to deal with the varying image widths, I think that you will need one of these four things:

- inline styles created manually (as you have now)
- inline styles created in server-side code
- width of text blocks adjusted with javascript
- single-row table for each image-and-text block

Perhaps it is just a failure of my imagination, but I don't see that this layout can be done without setting specific paragraph widths somehow, or using a single-row table for each block.

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't provide, so far as I'm aware, any means for conditional operators, or logic-based operations. This means that you're limited in your choices to:

1. server-side image-adjustments
2. client-side image-, or style-, adjustments
3. using css to apply a consistent width to the images

Of all of these, I'll address point three, which offers a couple of options.

The first is to use:

`img  {width: 100px; /* or whatever */ }`

The second is restricted to working with only `absolute` positioned images:

`img {clip: rect(0 100 100 0); } /* which will take the original image and clip it to the specified dimensions (top, right, bottom, left) */`

Answer (score 0):

The inline style thing is taken care of easily. Add a class to `.item` like `.big`, with the HTML then being, for example,

```
<div class="item big">
```

and the style being

```
.item.big .itemIcon { width: 160px; padding-left: -170px; }
.item.big .itemBody { margin-left: 170px; }
```

There is no way to dynamically change numbers using CSS alone. You can use javascript or a server-side function to insert class names and such. If you're automatically generating the images, you'd handle this at the same time. If you're doing it by hand, adding a class once makes it a lot easier.

Answer (score -1):

OMG everyone forgot table:). I guess table is good fit for this kind of problems.

```
<div class="item"> 
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="image">
    <div class="itemIcon" >
      <img src="icon.png" alt=""/> 
      <p>This is the caption that is under the image.</p>  
    </div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div class="itemBody" >    
      <h1>This is the first item</h1>
      <p>Aliquid aliquam fabulas duo an, eu delenit intellegebat has, in sit commodo aliquip. Inermis neglegentur vis an, ea mei habeo animal verterem. Cum vivendo intellegam disputando id, usu id dicta harum convenire. Cibo corpora ut pri, sed legere probatus aliquyam no, vidisse suscipiantur eu mea. Modus etiam concludaturque pro an, ut latine quaeque per. Harum ignota mnesarchum pri ad, duo et diam oblique epicurei, pri ne vivendo omnesque epicurei.</p> 
      <p>Aliquid aliquam fabulas duo an, eu delenit intellegebat has, in sit commodo aliquip. Inermis neglegentur vis an, ea mei habeo animal verterem. Cum vivendo intellegam disputando id, usu id dicta harum convenire. Cibo corpora ut pri, sed legere probatus aliquyam no, vidisse suscipiantur eu mea. Modus etiam concludaturque pro an, ut latine quaeque per. Harum ignota mnesarchum pri ad, duo et diam oblique epicurei, pri ne vivendo omnesque epicurei.</p> 
    </div> 
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

td.image {
     vertical-align:top;
    }
```